# Rancher Container Utilization stats stuck on Connecting

Tags: graph, docker, server, utilization, rancher

I have been using Rancher for a few weeks, but I have never managed to get the Utilization Stats working for Containers. It just sits there saying Connecting...

Utilization stats work for the Hosts, but not containers.

The Rancher Agent is on the same machine as the host, so I launched it with -e CATTLE_AGENT_IP=192.168.0.202 (Host and agents IP) but still nothing.

I also tried using a Debian VM on a second server, but I had the same trouble.

Running the Windows docker quickstart terminal on my personal machine and using that as an Agent, bizarrely did work however.

The same thing happens whether or not I choose managed network, or bridged.

I have looked for weeks but found no solid answer, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Host machine information:

```
Containers: 13
 Running: 9
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 419
Server Version: 1.11.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 366
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 5.824 GiB
Name: docker-master
ID: RWV7:2ZB4:RSVP:252L:IHNV:NKO7:OAXL:UNXV:7G5F:HWLX:BAMZ:75TK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Username: monkstick
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

Docker quickstart terminal (The one that works)

```
$ docker info
Containers: 6
 Running: 2
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 4
Images: 6
Server Version: 1.11.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 76
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.4.8-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.11.1 (TCL 7.0); HEAD : 7954f54 - Wed Apr 27 16:36:45 UTC 2016
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 995.9 MiB
Name: default
ID: MXGF:WKLT:6DNK:I2GI:QUOK:TRRE:J32A:QEFX:PQTB:OX6S:UF3R:4325
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 27
 Goroutines: 49
 System Time: 2016-05-31T13:06:53.122903718Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

[Rancher connecting window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Tfr.png)